# Effective Java Item 9, is the CaseInsensitiveString example correct?

Tags: java, effective-java

I'm reading the second edition of the book, page 36. I don't understand the solution to the simmetry problem:

```
@override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString &&
        ((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s.equalsIgnoreCase(s);
}
```

If I have the `CaseInsensitiveString cis= new CaseInsensitiveString("hello")` and the `String s="hello"` this behaves in a non-symmetric manner, because `s.equals(cis)` 
is true, but `cis.equals(s)`
is false...

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you actually tried `s.equals(cis)`?

Comment: Please share how the `equals()` method is overriden in `CaseInsensitiveString`. It's probably something to do with that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is correct, because symmetry is not violated. You're wrong concerning `s.equals(cis)`. It will return `false` in any case as `String` internally tests if the other object is also instanceof `String` and returns `false` if not. (And `CaseInsensitiveString` does *not* extend `String`.)

So as `s.equals(cis)` is `false` and `cis.equals(s)` is `false`, symmetry is given.

**Sidenote about `instanceof`**

Note that `String#equals(Object o)` uses `o instanceof String` to check the type of its argument. This is only correct because `String` is `final` and cannot be subclassed! Otherwise we could write a subclass of `String` and the following would happen:

```
String s = "Hello";
SubclassOfString sos = new SubclassOfString("Hello");
s.equals(sos) == true // as sos is instanceof String
sos.equals(s) == false // as s is NOT instanceof SubclassOfString
```

So if your classes are not `final`, use `this.getClass() == o.getClass()` instead of `instanceof` for type checking in `equals(Object)`!

Comment: Yes I missed that in the example CaseInsensitiveString doesn't extend String... Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3022586 Yes, that's the point. I've added a sidenote to address this issue.